# Use the Stoke's Theorem to evaluate $\oint_CF\cdot dr$, where $F(x,y,z) =(x+y^2)i+(y+z^2)j+(z+x^2)k$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

The question on the assignment is:
Use the Stoke's Theorem to evaluate $\oint_CF\cdot dr$, where $F(x,y,z) =(x+y^2)i+(y+z^2)j+(z+x^2)k$ and $C$ is a triangle with vertices $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ oriented counterclockwise as viewed from above.

Should I just start with finding the surface integral first, then proceed?

Comment: "Use Stokes' Theorem...." The whole point of the problem is to do the surface integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the problem says to use Stoke's theorem, you need to first find the curl, parameterize your surface, then integrate over the triangle.
\begin{align}
\nabla\times F&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(z+x^2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(y+z^2)\right)i\\
&-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(z+x^2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(x+y^2)\right)j\\
&+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y+z^2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+y^2)\right)k\\
&=-2z\,i-2x\,j-2y\,k
\end{align}
Hopefully you can take it from here.